# call method on button click using Url.Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
<td><button id="@questions.QbId" onclick="@Url.Action("ViewQuestionDetails","Admin" , new { QBID=questions.QbId })" class="btn btn-primary">View</button></td>
```

on button click i need to call a method in controller by using Qbid but it is not working

Comment: A button is not a hyperlink. If you want to do this without JavaScript then use a hyperlink.

Answer (score 2):

```
<td><button id="@questions.QbId" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("ViewQuestionDetails", "Admin", new {QBID=questions.QbId})'">View</button></td>
```

Comment: Provide some explanation of what this will do.